# Get single prediction values scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a confusion matrix and need to retrieve the values predicted by Random Forest. Currently I'm calling the cross-validation function, which only returns the score.

I know that there is a function `confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred[, labels])` from `sklearn.metrics` and I also have `y_true` given (see `y` from `prepareDataset(..)` ).

But I need `y_pred` as well. My relevant code snippet:

```
    ...

    # Define classifier.
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=self.n_estimators)
    # Explicitly define cv
    cv = StratifiedKFold(y, self.cv_folds)
    # Write out the actual splits
    ts = time.time()
    outlist = list(cv)

    with open(outPath, 'wb') as out:
        pickle.dump(outlist,out)

    # Perform crossvalidation.
    cv_scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(rfc, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs = 1)#, n_jobs=-1)
    # Calculate score and standard deviation.
    score = np.mean(cv_scores)
    std = np.std(cv_scores)

    ...

def prepareDataset(self, dataset):
    """" Splits the dataset in training- and target-dataset. """
    X = np.delete(dataset, dataset.shape[1] - 1, 1) # Training attributes.
    y = dataset[:,len(dataset[0]) - 1] # Training target.
```

So how can I get the list of predictions to feed `confusion_matrix(...)` with?

Or is there any other more simple way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you might have to iterate through your `cv` object manually and fit the classifier and store the predictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [cross_validation.cross_val_predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_predict.html). It would look something like this:

```
y_pred = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(rfc, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the job for me. As a side note I had trouble because the function could not be resolved until I recognized that I also had to upgrade my scikit-learn module, since this function is only available at version 0.16 and above.